Using multiple databases in YII2
I'm using a single database connection.
In /config/db.php file I wrote:
<?php
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=myhost1;port=5432;dbname=mydbname1',
    'username' => 'user1',
    'password' => 'password1',
    'charset' => 'utf8',   
];

Everything works fine, but now I need to use a connection to two databases. How can I do it?

Create new instance of yii\db\Connection

You define two database connections in your config:
return [
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=first_db',
        'username' => 'first_db_username',
        'password' => 'first_db_password',
    ],
    'second_db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=second_db',
        'username' => 'second_db_username',
        'password' => 'second_db_password',
    ],
],
];

Now if you are using ActiveRecord, you need to overwrite getDb() if you want to use your second database:
public static function getDb() {
    return Yii::$app->second_db;
}

